# WPF application needs to hold keystrokes in memory

Tags: .net, wpf, c#-4.0

I have a WPF app, where the user clicks on a button and another wpf form opens up where he types in a name. By default the focus is on the Name TextBox. So as soon as he gets the screen he can start typing. Now the user clicks the button and very quickly starts typing in the name even before the form has opened. In most cases whatever he has typed goes into that text box after the form opens, although he starts typing before the form has opened. However he has noticed that the first few letter goes missing in some cases.
I know why this happens. This is because .Net must be queuing up the letters before the form opens and then puts them there. However if he is typing names with large number of charecters, the queue looses the initial few letters.

Is there any way I can increase the size of this queue?

Comment: It's not queuing, it's because your window still doesn't exists and/or does not have the events hooked. You would not be able to solve this, maybe you can create a very lightweight form to open it as fast as it can be and when typing is done then open the real form and set the content.

Comment: Then how come the smaller names get properly to the textbox even though they are typed before the form opens? Why only the initial letters are missing from longer names? Why nothing is missing for smaller names?

Comment: If that where the case then what would be lost would be the final part, not the beginning as the buffer would be filled and the new events ignored.

Comment: So you think there is a buffer? how do I increase size of this buffer?

Comment: No, I don't think there is a buffer, I think you are missing the first events because the form does not exists or the events aren't hooked

Comment: They're typing before the window has focus. Not much you can do about that, other than make opening the window as fast as possible (e.g., put off initialization work onto the Dispatcher at a low DispatcherPriority).

Comment: how come I not miss the first event for smaller names and miss them consistently for longer names? This is a consistent repro.

Comment: If you are testing it "by hand" then a lot of factors can influenciate it, create a function which does a SendKeys and retest again with short and long names. Anyway, if you really want to be sure attach to the WndProc, the WndProc is the function which receives window messages and the keyboard presses are propagated through this mechanism. If really is a buffer problem in the WndProc you will see all the key messages and you can then do whatever you want with them

Comment: How fast is the window opening and how quickly do their freakin hands move? I feel like if the window opens relatively quick they have to be putting in quite the effort to start typing before it opens up.

Comment: Actually there is a Alt + p shortcut ... Window takes only about 1sec to 1.5 sec .. that time is enough for a normal person to type 5 to 10 letters. Yes these guys are freaky fast.